# Property 'productCategoryName' not found on type java.lang.String

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

I have checked as much as i can ,but i could not find where the problem is , i have seen few stack overflow Questions related to mine but mostly they all seems missing # .
    and i have seen somewhere that old version of mojora lib may cause this exceptions.i checked Names i am using in hibernate beans they all looks good but am not able to locate the problem .....

My Html Page:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">

<h:body>

    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="category" value="Admin" />
        <ui:param name="item" value="Create User" />
        <ui:param name="user" value="#{createUserAccountBean}" />
        <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="productsForm">
                <div class="headerbg">
                    <div id="innerheaderbg">
                        <div id="iconarea">
                            <img src="#{request.contextPath}/images/headerimages/productlist.png" />
                        </div>
                        <div id="headertextarea">
                            <p class="headingtext">Order</p>
                            <p id="breadCrumbtext">Order &#160;<img src="#{request.contextPath}/images/error-bullet.gif" />
                                &#160;Product Category List
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="otherarea"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <p:growl />


             <div class="widget widget-table action-table">
                <div class="widget-header"> <i class="icon-th-list"></i>
                    <h3>Product List</h3>
                <p:spacer width="10px" height="30px"/>  
                <h:outputLabel value="Product Category" style="color:#0A8FFF;font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:50px;"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{productBean.productCategoryId}" id="pFilter" >
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="--All--" itemValue="all" noSelectionOption="false"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{productCategoryBean.categoriesList}" var="category" 
                                               itemLabel="#{category.productCategoryName}"
                                               itemValue="#{category.productCategoryId}" />
                        <p:ajax update=":productsForm:productsTable" event="change" listener="#{productBean.filterProducts}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                </div>  <!-- /widget-header -->

                <div class="widget-content">

                    <p:dataTable id="productsTable" value="#{productBean.products}" var="products" rowIndexVar="rowIndex"  
                             paginator="true" rows="10" paginatorPosition="bottom" 
                             paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}" widgetVar="dt_products">
                    <p:column headerText="S.No">#{rowIndex+1}</p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Product Name">#{products.name}</p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Product Code">#{products.code}</p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Price">#{products.price}</p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>


                </div>  <!-- /widget-content -->
            </div>
            </h:form>
            <br></br>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and here is my bean, ProductCategoryBean.java:

```
    @Named(value = "productCategoryBean")
    @Scope("session")
    public class ProductCategoryBean 
    {
        private java.util.List<ProductCategory> categoriesList;

    public java.util.List<ProductCategory> getCategoriesList() 
    {
        categoriesList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
        return categoriesList;
    }

    public void setCategoriesList(java.util.List<ProductCategory> categoriesList) 
    {
        this.categoriesList = categoriesList;
    }
    }
```

Am Initializing categories list while Login  in at LoginBean.java

```
    @Named(value = "loginBean")
    @Scope("session")
    public class LoginBean {

        @Inject
        private UserService userService;

        @Inject
        private StocktrackService stocktrackService;

        @Inject
        private MenuController menuController;

        @Inject
        private CheckOut checkOut;


        @Inject
        private ProductCategoryBean categoryBean;

        @Inject
        private ProductsBean productsBean;


        private String userName;
        private String password;
        private String statusMessage;

        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getStatusMessage() {
            return statusMessage;
        }

        public void setStatusMessage(String statusMessage) {
            this.statusMessage = statusMessage;
        }

        public String login() throws EncryptionException, ServiceException 
        {
            StringEncrypter se = new StringEncrypter("DES");
            String encpassword = se.encrypt(getPassword());
            UserAccount userAccount = userService.validateLogin(userName,
                    encpassword);
            if (userAccount == null) {
                statusMessage = "The username or password is incorrect.";
                return "login.xhtml";
            }
            session.setAttribute("UserAccount", userAccount);
            statusMessage = "";
            menuController.setTopmenu(menuLoader(userAccount));
                checkOut.setUserId(userAccount.getUserId());
                checkOut.setUsername(userAccount.getUserName());
                checkOut.setUserAccount(userAccount);

            //setting category list of ProductCategoryBean
            categoryBean.setCategoriesList(stocktrackService.getProductCategory());
            //setting product list of ProductListBean
            productsBean.setProducts(stocktrackService.getProduct());

            return "/pages/leave/home.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        }
         }
```

Am getting the following Error:

```
> Feb 09, 2015 1:04:54 PM
> com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy
> handleRenderException SEVERE: Error Rendering
> View[/pages/order/products.xhtml] javax.faces.FacesException:
> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pages/order/products.xhtml @52,59
> itemLabel="#{category.productCategoryName}": Property
> 'productCategoryName' not found on type java.lang.String  at
> javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap.get(UIComponentBase.java:2364)
>   at
> org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.createSelectItem(InputRenderer.java:102)
>   at
> org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getSelectItems(InputRenderer.java:86)
>   at
> org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:71)
>   at
> org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:65)
>   at
> javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
>   at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)    at
> javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
>   at
> com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419)
>   at
> com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
>   at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
>   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Problem is that you are already using the parameter-name `category` and that it refers to a `String`

```
<ui:param name="category" value="Admin" />
```

And then you are reusing the parameter-name in `f:selectItems`,

```
<f:selectItems value="#{productCategoryBean.categoriesList}" var="category" 
      itemLabel="#{category.productCategoryName}"
      itemValue="#{category.productCategoryId}" />
```

but as it is already defined as an `ui:param` you are getting the given Exception. To resolve this, just use another name for the `var` in `f:selectItems`:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{productCategoryBean.categoriesList}" var="productCategory" 
      itemLabel="#{productCategory.productCategoryName}"
      itemValue="#{productCategory.productCategoryId}" />
```

Comment: :Wonderful , its working .could you kindly tell me the best practise to avoid and debug this kind of errors in web applications.Normally what do you do to debug this kind of situations . because the code has been written by some one and now am implementing ..... wasted 6 hours brother ....